# Where is the C++ operators are initially defined?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The topic we covered operator overloaded. They say the defined operators of C++ have already different meaning then you should create another ones. My question is where the initial C++ operators are defined, I mean which library have these operator implementation for default?

Comment: They are not part of a library, they are built in to the compiler.

Comment: How can reach that the compiler information?

Answer (score 1):

The standard operators are not defined in any library, they are built into the language and implemented by the compiler. Libraries and user code can then overload them as needed.